# get image from photoLibrary and display on tableview Cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to get image from photo library and show image on tableview cell.

yes, I know, we can use  let pickedImageFromGallery = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as! UIImage
imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method.

**but I want to get the image from photo library as String and display on cell.**

how can I do that?

Comment: An image is not a string so what are we talking about?

Comment: What you mean "display as a string"?

Comment: "display as a string"? You mean you want to display the name of image or something?

Comment: @EmreGürses
**my array is type of string**, so i want to show an image on tableview cell.
i don't know how to get in string type array and display on cel.

Comment: Your post is really poor. Please add a code block or explain what your need. We can not understand clearly

Answer (score -2):

First, you need to convert to binary data:  NSData or Data

Second, convert to string

Comment: did you mean
i get image as **info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as! UIImage**  and then convert to binary data ro NSData or Data, then i convert it string right?